# Constructor __init__ is written to take two position arguments, but when used, reports the error that only 1 is allowed

Tags: python, constructor

I have a class and constructor I'm working on, and I added an extra parameter to `__init__`, and now I get the error, `TypeError: FeatureDataset() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

I wonder why. It seems to me that it should accept two arguments. It's an incomplete function, but I'd like to get past this constructor argument number error. I have checked several answers and either they were about something specifically different, or indentation, and I have neither of those issues (4 indents per new indentation divide).

```
def FeatureDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, root_dir, file_name):

        #load csv
        self.file_out = pd.read_csv(file_name)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.labels = self.file_out.iloc[1:160, 0].values
        self.features = self.file_out.iloc[1:160, 1:].values

        #Feature Scaling
        sc = StandardScaler()
        label_train = self.labels
        feature_train = self.features #sc.fit_transform(features)

        #Convert to torch tensors
        self.feature_train = torch.tensor(label_train, dtype = torch.float32)
        self.label_train = torch.tensor(label_train)

file_name = "data.csv"
root_dir = "archive"
feature_set = FeatureDataset(root_dir, file_name)
```

Comment: shouldn't FeatureDataset() be a class? instead of def?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Thank you so much. Finally starting to feel natural with python, but a thing or two slips me up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This defines a function, not a class:

```
def FeatureDataset(Dataset):
```

... try ...

```
class FeatureDataset(Dataset):
```